# How to run procedure with parameters in another thread using C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am stuck at trying to call a procedure and use some parameters in a new thread in C#. There is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace Random_colored_rectangles
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Thread th;
        Random rand;
        System.Drawing.Color[] colors = new System.Drawing.Color[5] {Color.Orange, Color.Red, Color.Pink, Color.Black, Color.Gold };

        private void DrawColor(Color color)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                DrawRectangle(color, 3 , rand.Next(0, this.Width), rand.Next(0, this.Height), 10, 10);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            MessageBox.Show(color + " done");
        }

        private void DrawRectangle(Color barva, float width, int pos_x, int pos_y, int size_x, int size_y)
        {
            Pen myPen = new Pen(barva, width);

            Graphics formGraphics;
            formGraphics = plocha.CreateGraphics();
            formGraphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, new Rectangle(pos_x, pos_y, size_x, size_y));
            myPen.Dispose();
            formGraphics.Dispose();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rand = new Random();
        }

        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.R)
            {
                th = new Thread(DrawColor);
                th.Name = Convert.ToString(threadCount);
                threadList.Add(th);
                threadCount = threadCount + 1;
                th.Start(colors[rand.Next(0, colors.Length)]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code should (after pressing `R`) make 100 random colored rectangles (the color is chosen from an array of few colors). But, I am unable to make my thread start the procedure `DrawColor` with a parameter of the random color select.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Side note from language police: methods in C# are called "method"... When you use "procedure" it usually refers to Pascal or SQL...

Comment: You don't need a Thread, you can't use one for GUI work. You need a Timer.

Comment: And you should avoid this.CreateGraphics() too. You probably want to them to stay after a Refrash(), don't you?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by using a `Task`.

```
Color theColorToPass = someColor;
Task.Factory.StartNew(color => {
  DrawColor(color);
}, theColorToPass);
```

You could aswell access the array directly from within the Task though. I see no point in passing it to the Thread.

Comment: While technically correct answer to question specified in title, this code will not work correctly in any of .Net UI frameworks due to cross-thread access to UI elements.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Aye. Was just about to post an edit. You will have to wrap this up in this.Invoke((delegate) { ... }); or something along the line.

Answer (score -1):

Using the advice of those more familiar with the do's and don'ts of C# (that is not me trying to sound mean or anything), I have devised a way to accomplish what you want without the need of `CreateGraphics()` or `Thread.Sleep()`. Unfortunately, this throws an `OutOfMemoryException` when it hits `e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(penToUse, rectanglesToUse[0]);`. What does that mean?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Colors
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer { Interval = 100 };
        Random rand = new Random();
        Color[] colors = new Color[5]
        {
            Color.Black,
            Color.Blue,
            Color.Green,
            Color.Purple,
            Color.Red
        };

        List<Pen> usedPens = new List<Pen>();
        List<Rectangle> usedRectangles = new List<Rectangle>();

        Pen penToUse;
        List<Rectangle> rectanglesToUse = new List<Rectangle>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
            {
                penToUse = new Pen(GetRandomColor(), 3);

                rectanglesToUse.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    rectanglesToUse.Add(GetRandomRectangle());

                this.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private Color GetRandomColor()
        {
            return colors[rand.Next(0, colors.Length)];
        }

        private Rectangle GetRandomRectangle()
        {
            return new Rectangle(rand.Next(0, Width), rand.Next(0, Height), 10, 10);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < usedRectangles.Count; i++)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(usedPens[i % 100], usedRectangles[i]);

            timer.Tick += delegate
            {
                if (rectanglesToUse.Count > 0)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(penToUse, rectanglesToUse[0]);
                    usedRectangles.Add(rectanglesToUse[0]);
                    rectanglesToUse.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    usedPens.Add(penToUse);
                    timer.Stop();
                }
            };
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work it'll raise the cross-threading exception. Besides, CreateGraphics() and Thread.Sleep() should be avoided.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, this _did_ work for me or else I wouldn't have posted it as an answer.

Comment: I didn't try this but you probably just circumvented the check. It still isn't thread-safe and keeping a captured Graphics alive for 10 seconds is ... unwise.

Comment: What changes do you suggest? And wouldn't calling `CreateGraphics()` every time be inefficient?

Comment: 'inefficient' would be the least of your problems here. And is always a bit silly to worry about  for code that `Sleep()`s. I already posted my suggestions under the question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does one get a `Graphics` object to work with in this scenario if you shouldn't call `CreateGraphics()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81816/discussion-between-minato-and-henk-holterman).